# Xcode XCTest how to test an UILabel has truncated text in UITesting

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I am trying to write some UITests to test whether my label's text will be truncated on a smaller device.

I can be able to get the label's text, but actually in XCTest is's atually of type XCUIElementType, so no way of implementing UI checking since it is not an UI element.

Anyway I can do it?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can get the label (`String`) of `XCUIElement` with `.label` var.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/attributename/3022461-label

2. If you want to know if the truncating function was called, change element's accessibility identifier at the end of the function (e.g., from `myLabel` -> `myLabel.trunc`). Then, assert identifier in test code.
3. If you want to verify the element's appearance, you need screenshot testing (e.g., with https://github.com/uber/ios-snapshot-test-case )

Comment: Yeah I can be able to get the label using .label, but even when the label's string is truncated, for example: "This is ....", when I print the .label out I am still getting the full string "This is a test string"

Comment: Added more options.